# Android studio version 2.3 not working

Tags: android, android-studio

[How to solve this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fD8ux.jpg)  Today I installed android studio2.3 version but it is showing this problm

Comment: Did you click it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to just update your SDK. From your Android Studio menu bar Select Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager -> SDK Platforms -> Android 7.1.1 checked and clicked Apply and OK. Then your Nougat version will update and your problem will be solved... :)

Answer (score 0):

Gradle build error is shown when your SDK doesn't have the required API level, which is mentioned in build.gradle (app module) file. One way to solve this problem is lower the API level in you build.gradle file that is installed in your SDK, other way is **Farya** mentioned in her answer.